# How do I do a better algorithm (Big list with variable names)

Tags: c#, regex

The companies names are much variable, so i add much or conditions.

Maybe any have bether way with regex to do this?

Im store the values im needed in different groups.

Thanks for any help!

I have added only a part from the text, the complete text is to big! Hope this helps in Futur! The Link have the complete List.

```
Unternehmen; Symbol; Valorennummer; Land; Handelswährung; Handels-platform; Indexzugehörigkeit; Papierart; Nennwert; Branche; Kotierungs-segment; Rechnungslegungsnorm; Nächste Generalversammlung; Primär-kotiert;
3M Company; MMM; 1405105; US; CHF; XSWX; ; RS; 0.00; ; International Reporting Standard; ; ; false;
5EL SA; FEL; 632685; CH; CHF; XSWX; ; BS; 40.00; Equity Investment Instruments; International Reporting Standard; IFRS; ; true;
ABB Ltd; ABBN; 1222171; CH; CHF; XVTX; SMI,SPI,SLCI,SMIEXP,SLI; RS; 0.12; Industrial Engineering; International Reporting Standard; US GAAP; 13.04.17; true;
Abbott Laboratories; ABT; 903037; US; CHF; XSWX; ; RS; 0.00; ; International Reporting Standard; ; ; false;
AbbVie Inc; ABBV; 20145667; US; CHF; XSWX; ; RS; 0.00; ; International Reporting Standard; ; ; false;
Accu Holding AG; ACUN; 136633; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; RS; 10.00; Household Goods; Swiss Reporting Standard; Swiss GAAP FER; ; true;
Actelion Ltd.; ATLN; 1053247; CH; CHF; XVTX; SMI,SPI,SLCI,SLIFE,SBIOM,SMIEXP,SLI; RS; 0.50; Pharmaceuticals & Biotechnology; International Reporting Standard; US GAAP; 05.04.17; true;
Addex Therapeutics Ltd; ADXN; 2985075; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; RS; 1.00; Pharmaceuticals & Biotechnology; International Reporting Standard; IFRS; ; true;
Adecco Group AG; ADEN; 1213860; CH; CHF; XVTX; SMI,SPI,SLCI,SMIEXP,SLI; RS; 1.00; Support Services; International Reporting Standard; US GAAP; 20.04.17; true;
Adval Tech Holding AG; ADVN; 896792; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; RS; 20.00; Industrial Engineering; Swiss Reporting Standard; Swiss GAAP FER; 18.05.17; true;
AEVIS VICTORIA SA; AEVS; 1248819; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX,SLIFE,SBIOM; RS; 5.00; Health Care Equipment & Services; Swiss Reporting Standard; Swiss GAAP FER; 13.06.17; true;
Airesis SA; AIRE; 1094762; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; RS; 0.25; Personal Goods; International Reporting Standard; IFRS; 12.06.17; true;
Airopack Technology Group AG; AIRN; 24260694; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; RS; 5.00; Technology Hardware & Equipment; Swiss Reporting Standard; Swiss GAAP FER; 10.05.17; true;
Allreal Holding AG; ALLN; 883756; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SMCI,SPIEX; RS; 50.00; Real Estate; Immobiliengesellschaften; IFRS; 21.04.17; true;
Alpine Select AG; ALPN; 1919955; CH; CHF; XSWX; ; RS; 0.02; Equity Investment Instruments; Investmentgesellschaften; IFRS; 22.05.17; true;
Alpiq Holding AG; ALPH; 3438970; CH; CHF; XSWX; ; RS; 10.00; Electricity; International Reporting Standard; IFRS; 18.05.17; true;
ALSO Holding AG; ALSN; 2459027; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; RS; 1.00; Technology Hardware & Equipment; International Reporting Standard; IFRS; 21.03.17; true;
Altin AG; ALTN; 1442452; CH; USD; XSWX; ; RS; 0.03; Equity Investment Instruments; Investmentgesellschaften; IFRS; ; true;
ams AG; AMS; 24924656; AT; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SMCI,SPIEX,SMIM,SMIEXP; BS; 0.00; Technology Hardware & Equipment; International Reporting Standard; IFRS; 09.06.17; true;
Anglo American plc; AAM; 3186826; GB; CHF; XSWX; ; RS; 0.55; ; International Reporting Standard; ; ; false;
APG SGA SA; APGN; 1910702; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SMCI,SPIEX; RS; 2.60; Media; Swiss Reporting Standard; Swiss GAAP FER; 23.05.17; true;
Arbonia AG; ARBN; 11024060; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; RS; 4.20; Construction & Materials; International Reporting Standard; IFRS; 28.04.17; true;
Arundel AG; ARON; 227101; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; RS; 9.50; Real Estate; International Reporting Standard; IFRS; 19.09.17; true;
ARYZTA AG; ARYN; 4323836; CH; CHF; XVTX; SPI,SMCI,SPIEX,SMIM,SMIEXP,SLI; RS; 0.02; Food Producers; International Reporting Standard; IFRS; 06.12.17; true;
Ascom Holding AG; ASCN; 1133920; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SMCI,SPIEX; RS; 0.50; Technology Hardware & Equipment; Swiss Reporting Standard; Swiss GAAP FER; 19.04.17; true;
Autoneum Holding AG; AUTN; 12748036; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SMCI,SPIEX; RS; 0.05; Automobiles & Parts; International Reporting Standard; IFRS; 30.03.17; true;
Bachem Holding AG; BANB; 1253020; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX,SLIFE; RS; 0.05; Pharmaceuticals & Biotechnology; Swiss Reporting Standard; Swiss GAAP FER; 24.04.17; true;
Baker Hughes Incorporated; BHI; 910918; US; CHF; XSWX; ; RS; 1.00; ; International Reporting Standard; ; ; false;
Boloise Holding AG; BALN; 1241051; CH; CHF; XVTX; SPI,SMCI,SPIEX,SMIM,SMIEXP,SLI; RS; 0.10; Nonlife Insurance; International Reporting Standard; IFRS; 28.04.17; true;
Bank Coop AG; BC; 1811647; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; BS; 20.00; Banks; Swiss Reporting Standard; Bankengesetz; 20.04.17; true;
Bank Linth LLB AG; LINN; 130775; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; RS; 20.00; Banks; Swiss Reporting Standard; Bankengesetz; 20.04.17; true;
Banque Cantonale de Geneve; BCGE; 35049471; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; RS; 50.00; Banks; Swiss Reporting Standard; Bankengesetz; 25.04.17; true;
Banque Cantonale du Jura SA; BCJ; 3299134; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; BS; 14.00; Banks; Swiss Reporting Standard; Bankengesetz; 27.04.17; true;
Banque Cantonale Vaudoise; BCVN; 1525171; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SMCI,SPIEX; RS; 10.00; Banks; Swiss Reporting Standard; Bankengesetz; 27.04.17; true;
Banque Profil de Gestion S.A.; BPDG; 249229; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; BS; 1.00; General Financial; Swiss Reporting Standard; Bankengesetz; 26.04.17; true;
Barry Callebaut AG; BARN; 900296; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SMCI,SPIEX,SMIM,SMIEXP; RS; 7.29; Food Producers; International Reporting Standard; IFRS; 13.12.17; true;
Basellandschaftliche Kantonalbank; BLKB; 147355; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SMCI,SPIEX; PC; 100.00; Banks; Swiss Reporting Standard; Bankengesetz; 03.04.17; true;
BASF SE; BAS; 11450563; DE; CHF; XSWX; ; RS; 0.00; ; International Reporting Standard; ; ; false;
Basilea Pharmaceutica AG; BSLN; 1143244; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SMCI,SPIEX,SLIFE,SBIOM; RS; 1.00; Pharmaceuticals & Biotechnology; International Reporting Standard; US GAAP; 27.04.17; true;
Basler Kantonalbank; BSKP; 923646; CH; CHF; XSWX; SPI,SSCI,SPIEX; PC; 8.50; Banks; Swiss Reporting Standard; Bankengesetz; 27.04.17; true;
Baxter International Inc.; BAX; 911702; US; CHF; XSWX; ; RS; 1.00; ; International Reporting Standard; ; ; false;
BB Biotech AG; BION; 3838999; CH; CHF; XSWX; SLIFE,SBIOM; RS; 0.20; Pharmaceuticals & Biotechnology; Investmentgesellschaften; IFRS; 16.03.17; true;
BELIMO Holding AG; BEAN; 150319; CH; CHF; XSWX;
```

```
(\w+\s\w+\s\w+\.\w+\.|\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\.\w+\.|\w+\s\w+\s\w+\.|\w+\s\w+\s\&\s\w+\s\w+|\w+\s\w+\-\w+\-\w+\s\w+|\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+|\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+|\w+\s\w+\s\w+|\w+\s\w+);\s(\w+);\s(\d+);\s(\w+);\s(\w+);\s(\w+);
```

https://regex101.com/r/IfBFIL/1

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the question itself. Links to external sites tend to stop working, making the question useless for people that stumble across it in the future.

Comment: Have added some Text of the File and the regex. I thought that I would not spam the page with text, so I have the link deposited. I meant it well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex, I think, is at least slightly easier on the eyes (the horror!), and seems to parse the data ok:

```
(?<company>.*?);(?<prefix>.*?);.(?<number>\d*?);(?<code1>.*?);(?<code2>.*?);(?<code3>.*?);.*$
```

*we make use of the fact that the data is well delimited with semi-colons, and we want the first 'however many' fields - which each successive and (nearly) identical named match group represents.

the `.*?` is the same as the "greedy" version: `.*`, but it starts at matching none (instead of all), and then matches more as necessary.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IfBFIL/3)

Comment: Awesome dude! That is what i want! Thanks alot!

Comment: (.*?);\s(\w+);\s(\d+);\s(\w+);\s(\w+);\s(\w+);  :) dont know the (.*?). Thanks again for your example! Ah maybe u can desciption for what i can set the name of the group?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx  you can of course, give the groups any names you want - you probably know what these fields should be named better than I :)

Comment: Ah that represents the ID, if im see that correctly as example: match.Groups["GroupName"].Value. So that looks way better for the eyes. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks pretty consistent with the 15th item always being the company name:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
int count = 0;
foreach (string s in yourData.Split(';')) {
  count++;
  if (count == 15) {
    items.Add(s);
    count = 1;
  }
}
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items.ToArray()));
```

Comment: This way would be easier but various other code parts I would like to avoid. Since I'm learning at regex I would like to know how to do it better with regex :)

Comment: In my opinion, @LarsTech did a pretty good job in guiding you towards a solution. I understand your willingness to learn regex, but you also have to use the right tools for the right job. Using regex can become extremely complex. As an example, I would tell you to look at the regex to parse an email address(RFC 5322 Official Standard) http://emailregex.com/ to understand what I mean. There may be cases you may have not thought of also when implementing regex! Good luck and be careful!

Comment: I understand what you mean. If I had time pressure I would make it as Larstech has described. It would be a good solution if you have to work under time pressure. But since I want to learn something and keep my code as nice as possible, it does not matter for me.

Comment: here will be other problems when splitting symbol ; see: International Reporting Standard; ; ; or IFRS; ;

Comment: @Lendoria Those aren't problems — those are empty entries for those columns.

Comment: @LarsTech Sry my fold^^

Answer (score 0):

It's a list of companies, date (optional), number (optional) and a bool value - all separated by ';'

So... split by the ';', then filter on a simple regex to exclude the known non-company name values:

```
Regex excludeRegex = new Regex(@"[\d\.]+|true|false", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string dataString = "asd;sdfsdf;f fff; 123.231; true; abb";

List<string> companies = dataString.Split(';',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(c=>c.Trim())
    .Where(c=>!excludeRegex.IsMatch(c))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a pattern.

[101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/IfBFIL/4)

`(?m)^\s*([^;]+?)\s*;\s*([^;]+?)\s*;\s*([^;]+?)\s*;\s*([^;]+?)\s*;\s*([^;]+?)\s*;\s*([^;]+?)\s*;(?=.*?(?:true|false);)`

```
 (?m)
 ^ \s* 
 ( [^;]+? )                    # (1)
 \s* ; \s* 
 ( [^;]+? )                    # (2)
 \s* ; \s* 
 ( [^;]+? )                    # (3)
 \s* ; \s* 
 ( [^;]+? )                    # (4)
 \s* ; \s* 
 ( [^;]+? )                    # (5)
 \s* ; \s* 
 ( [^;]+? )                    # (6)
 \s* ;
 (?=
      .*? 
      (?: true | false )
      ;
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That looks very complicated. Tomorrow I'll take a closer look.